# Qt (PyQt) globally available slots?

Tags: qt, pyqt

I have a fairly complex MVC structured application and I want a convenient way to update a QStatusBar from almost any part of it.  My understanding is that I would have to pass around a lot of references to my QStatusBar or set up a bunch of signals in my controllers.  It would get messy.

I also understand that QApplication is essentially a singleton.  Would it be an acceptable idea to add a slot to it so that I could get the instance of QApplication from anywhere and emit to it?

Alternatively, what is a reasonable way to communicate global-ish things in my application without littering the controllers and views with references to widgets parented elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about implement singleton, that allow communication between components and gui, something like:

```
#include <statuscontroller.h>

StatusController::instance()->setStatus("Status string");
```

In this case only StatusController contain pointer to QStatusBar and available globally in gui thread.

With QObject as base class for StatusController you could use signals and slots.

Comment: I was thinking of putting the singleton behaviour into QApplication.  But  I think this method works better.  Thanks!